# Listview rows order changes randomly while going details and come back to Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a ListView in a custom ArrayAdapter that displays an icon ImageView and a TextView in each row. while going listview detail page and come back to listview click item displaying bottom of the listview, the order is randomly changing while going to detail page and come back to list page.

how to fix it ?

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = vi.inflate(R.layout.listitemrow, null);
    }
    RssItem rssItem = (RssItem) super.getItem(position);
    if (rssItem != null)
    {
        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rowtitle);
        if (title != null)
        {
            title.setText(rssItem.getTitle());
        }
    }
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Show us the code you have

Comment: We also need the code where you call the detail, how do you close it, how you initialize/create your listview, how is your custom adapter ....

Comment: show your code when you implement onItemClick method

Comment: Are you sure its random data? The listView might have regenerated because of activity resume. So what you are seeing is actually the top of the list.

Comment: i have 3 items item1 , item2 and item3 when am cliking on item1 going details page and come back it showing item2 , item3 and item1 again am cliking on item2 going to detais page come back it showing item1 , item2 and item 3 item is showing randomly..